# How to generate a Backend Modul without Database in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I have a Backend Module which have been build using a Database with the commando (ex.)

> php symfony propel:generate-admin backend JobeetJob --module=job

Now i want to generate a Modul, which dont have a Database, but just showing a result using a sql request ex:

```
select v1."Venue", 
( select count(*) 
    from "Events" e1 where e1."VenueNo" = v1."VenueNo"
) as "EventsCount"
from "venues" v1
order by "EventsCount" desc
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate a module that you can customize, that is adding your actions, according to your needs using this task:

```
php symfony generate:module  application module
```

You can find more details about this task in [The symfony Reference Book: Tasks](http://www.symfony-project.org/reference/1_4/en/16-Tasks)

Comment: Thanks! gonna try it! I just want to display some charts in Backend thats all!